# How to delete comments for Java project with sed?

Tags: java, bash, sed

I have a Java project, in which I have JavaDoc comments

```
/** ... */
```

other multi-line-comments

```
/* ... */
```

line comments

```
// ...
```

and my own "explanatory comments"

```
//* ...
```

When I release my code, I would like to have all line comments removed – not the other comments though. I though I would do it with sed, but so far I have not been successful. I am trying the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -d $'\0' findfile ; do
  echo "${findfile}"
  mv "${findfile}" "${findfile}".veryold
  cat "${findfile}".veryold | sed -e 's|//[^\*"]*[^"]*||' -e 's/[ ^I]*$//' | grep -A1 . | grep -v '^--$' > "${findfile}"
  rm -f "${findfile}".veryold
done < <(find "${1}" -type f -print0)
```

What am doing wrong? Note that `//` in `"..."` should not be removed, since they might be part of a URL.

The crucial part is

```
-e 's|//[^\*"]*[^"]*||'
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove your comments?

Comment: A matter of "clean code". Functions that are not required anymore, long text what I intend to do here, but have it implemented now, and especially alternative solutions. I like to keep alternative solutions in my code, to be able to look it up at a later point, but it is nothing my colleagues or customers want to see. That is why I would only like to delete this one type of comment. USEFUL comments are marked with //* by me.

Comment: Why do I get a downvote for that question??? It "shows research effort", it is "clear", and it is useful: In my last comment I explained why. Also simply: I would use it (so _obviously_ it is useful.)

Comment: what about recursive comment (comment in comment)

Comment: I don't see a reason why one should write // ... // ... in Java code, after all it is already omitted for the compiler. Netbeans comments lines out and reverts the lines back to the same code with the same shortcut so it doesn't happen by accident ether (opposite to Linux KDE tools, like Kate or Kile, but in that context that makes sense, I'm not going into details here). Also // ... //* ... makes little sense (think about it). Only //* ... // ... might make sense. It all cases I'd say: Delete the rest of the line from the first // (without *) onwards.

Comment: I do not really understand the `sed` command you tried. Why do you match a double `/` followed by any (including 0) number of anything but `*`, `"` or `)`, followed by any (including 0) number of anything but `"`?

Comment: The ) was a typo that I removed. The rest: I want to delete everything from any // to the end of the line, except if it is //* instead of just // - in that case I don't want anything deleted. The " is, because I don't additionally don't want anything deleted if there is a " in the line. I think I did a mistake there, because the " should be before //. In fact this is, because anything like " ... // ... " is not a comment, but the // is just part of a String, e.g. a URL. Clear now?

Answer (score 0):

For a test file that looks like this:

```java
/** This should stay */
/* And this
 * should stay
 * as well */
// This one should be removed
//* But this one should stay
code here // This part should go, but not the next line
"http://test.com"
code here //* This should stay
```

you can do it like this:

```
$ sed '\#^//[^*]#d;s#//[^*"][^"]*$##' test.java
/** This should stay */
/* And this
 * should stay
 * as well */
//* But this one should stay
code here
"http://test.com"
code here //* This should stay
```

The first expression, `\#^//[^*]#d`, deletes all lines that start with `//` (but not `//*`). This is to avoid getting empty lines in the output when the whole line is removed.

The second expression, `s#//[^*"][^"]*$##`, matches from `//` on (but not `//*` or `//"`), until the end of the line, unless there is a `"` between the `//` and the end of the line.

Your expression `s|//[^\*"]*[^"]*||` did almost the same, except:

- No need to escape characters in bracket expressions; `[\*]` matches both `\` and `*`.
- You want the first bracket expression to match just once, not zero or more times; your expression *does* match `//*`.
- You don't anchor at the end of the line, so this expressions matches `//` everywhere and removes them, even if followed by `"` or `*`.

For the peculiar case of a zero-length comment at the end of the line,

```
code here //
```

where you'd want to remove the `//`, you'd have to add a third substitution `s#//$/#` because the existing one expects at least one character after the `//`.

Notice how this is not super clean in that it might leave useless spaces at the end of lines, but that can easily be remedied by `s/[[:space:]]*$/$/`.